# How do I use a class of any type inside another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class. Inside that class I wish to use a method from another class. However, I don't want to be restricted to only one type of class, I want to be able to call this method from any class that contains the method.

```
public class DialogueSuper : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public choiceHandler ch = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void end(){
        ch.next()
    }
}
```

In the end() method I call the ch.next() method. However, I do not want to be restricted to a class of choiceHandler. I would like to call the next() method on any class I decide to pass into DialogueSuper that contains a next() method.

Comment: Maybe that's why we have interfaces?

Comment: Sounds like you want an interface containing the `Next`-method, that all your classes implement. Then instead of `public choiceHandler ch = null;` you may use `public ITheInterface ch = null;`

Comment: Define ch as `dynamic`. If next method is found in provided type then it will be invoked otherwise you have to handle runtime exception. Or use the type safe programming by using Interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach to solving this problem is to program to an interface.  `choiceHandler` is presumably a concrete class thus the problem.  Change this to `IChoiceHandler` which contains the member `Next`.

```
public interface IChoiceHandler
{
    void Next();
}
```

Any class that implements the interface can be injected as a dependency.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueSuper : MonoBehaviour
{

    public IChoiceHandler ch = null;

    public DialogueSuper(IChoiceHandler ch)
    {
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void end()
    {
        ch.Next()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is called Inversion of Control. You can implement that in the code through dependency injection. Basically the creator of `DialogueSuper` class's object will have the power to choose the `ChoiceHandler`. You can either make use of full blown IoC providers like Unity application block or write your own. For a simple need of this sort, you can probably write the `DialogueSuper` class like this:

First, have an interface and implement that in the choice handler class.

```
public interface IChoiceHandler
{
    void Next();
}

public class ChoiceHandler : IChoiceHandler
{
    public void Next() { }
}
```

Next, update the dialogue class with one of these options:

```
public class DialogueSuper : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Way 1: Property Injection
    public IChoiceHandler ChoiceHandler
    {
        get; set;
    }

    // Way 2: Constructor injection
    private IChoiceHandler _choiceHandler;

    private DialogueSuper() : base()
    {

    }

    public DialogueSuper(IChoiceHandler choiceHandler)
    {
        _choiceHandler = choiceHandler;
    }

    // Way 3: Method Injection
    public void end(IChoiceHandler choiceHandler)
    {
        // For way 1
        ChoiceHandler.Next();
        // For way 2
        _choiceHandler.Next();
        // For way 3
        choiceHandler.Next();
    }
}
```

Note that first option is more suitable if you are using an IoC provider. With current code, you are prone to `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

### Interfaces

**You generally do this by using [Interfaces in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/).**

A Interface is basically a contract. All classes that implement a Interface must provide the methods and properties specified in there.

```
interface IChoiceHandler
{
    void next();
}
```

First Imlementation of the Interface

```
class ChoiceHandler1 : IChoiceHandler
{
    public void next()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Another Imlementation of the Interface

```
class ChoiceHandler2 : IChoiceHandler
{
    public void next()
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

No you only require a class that implements the interface which defines the functionality you want.

```
class Example
{
    public Example(IChoiceHandler handler)
    {
        handler.next();
    }
}
```

### Dynamics

It is also possible to use [dynamics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic), but this is **not recommended** because it easily can create runtime errors.

```
class Example
{
    public Example(dynamic handler) => handler.next();   
}
```